# Why does Chromes XSS filter block injection into HTML element, but not into attribute?

Tags: xss, chrome, reflected-xss

I have this vulnerable code which takes a GET parameter, and puts it inside a HTML element (`h1`) as well as inside a HTML attribute (`data-text`):

```
$data = $_GET["payload"];
echo "<h1>" .$data. "</h1>";
echo '<div data-role="button"  data-text="' .$data.'"></div>';
```

The Chrome XSS auditor will block `<script>alert(1)</script>` in the first echo (inside the element), but not in the second (inside the attribute) even though the payload could be executed through a script gadget.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no vulnerability resulting from the HTML code in the second case (you would need to close the tags first, eg `'"><script>alert(1)</script>`; this would be caught by the auditor).

You may have JavaScript code which further processes your HTML code and thus introduces an XSS vulnerability in the second case as well (eg via [script gadgets](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Lekies-Dont-Trust-The-DOM-Bypassing-XSS-Mitigations-Via-Script-Gadgets.pdf)), but that is not what the [XSS Auditor](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/xss-auditor) monitors:

> **The XSS Auditor runs during the HTML parsing phase** and attempts to find **reflections** from the request to the response body. It does not attempt to mitigate Stored or DOM-based XSS attacks.

The JavaScript interpreter will be run [after](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#The_browser_high_level_structure) the HTML parser, so any vulnerabilities introduced by JavaScript will not be caught by the XSS auditor.

Comment: Only to the body of the response?
so if the input from the request goes to the data-text attribute on the div element its ok?

Comment: @Niv I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: in both request the input is the same, the only different is that in the first case the input goes between h1 tags and in the second case the input goes into data-text attribute.
so this why the xss auditor dont block it?

Comment: @Niv Right, the input is the same, but the result is different. In the first case, you introduce an XSS vulnerability *in the HTML code*. In the second case, there is *no* vulnerability; the browser will correctly interpret the input as text value for an attribute and not execute the malicious JavaScript code. A vulnerability *might* be introduced by a JavaScript library, but that is not what the XSS auditor monitors.